# A child flies a kite at a height of 300 feet. The wind carries the kite horizontally at a rate of 10 ft/sec....

Tags: calculus

A child flies a kite at a height of 300 feet. The wind carries the kite horizontally at a rate of 10 ft/sec. How fast must the child play out string when the kite is 500 feet from him?

I already know the answer is 8ft/sec, just not sure how to get to it?

Comment: http://webpages.math.luc.edu/~rgoebel1/TeachingArchive/Fall09Math161/pdf/q4sol.pdf

Comment: Why use the Pythagorean therom? This is what does not make sense to me